# Angular components from the same module ar enot recognized by the other

Tags: angular

I've just added storybook to my angular app, and created the following module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Icon } from './components/icon/icon.component';

import { Dropdown } from './components/dropdown/dropdown.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    Dropdown,
    Icon
  ],
  exports: [
    Dropdown,
    Icon
  ],
})
export class StorybookModule {}
```

in my dropdown component i'm trying to use the icon component **with the correct selector**:

```
<span *ngIf="icon"><p-icon [icon]="icon"></p-icon></span>
```

but for some reason im getting this error:

```
'p-icon' is not a known element:
```

any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Can you share the ts file of your icon component

Comment: You have p-icon tag and Icon class -- thats already strange

Comment: It should work if you put the Icon on declaration first and Dropdown second and make sure you kill ng serve and start again. Sometimes angular compiler get confused. I remember I got similar a long time back.